# How to code a search page for my website

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2012, windows-search, indexing-service

We have a search page on our website that we made using ASP Classic on Windows Server 2003.  Now we have migrated over to Windows Server 2012 and we need to make a new search page as the code will not work on Windows Server 2012 Search Service.
Has anyone come across this yet. I have been struggling trying to find good information on how to do this. If possible can someone show some coding examples on how this is done?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <%
    'Setup ADO objects.
    Set adoCommand    = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    adoConnection.Open "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';"
    Set adoCommand.ActiveConnection = adoConnection

    strQuery = "SELECT Top 1000 System.ItemPathDisplay FROM SYSTEMINDEX"

    adoCommand.CommandText = strQuery
    adoCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 10
    adoCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 30
    adoCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False

    ' Run the query.
    Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute


    adoRecordset.MoveFirst
Do Until adoRecordset.EOF
    response.write(adoRecordset.Fields.Item("System.ItemPathDisplay")& "<br />")
    adoRecordset.MoveNext
Loop

    ' Clean up.
    adoRecordset.Close
    adoConnection.Close
    %>
```